# no method error at index get request ruby

Tags: sql, ruby, sinatra

Any experts on hand for what I am sure is a quick fix. I am running sinatra with ruby controller & models, with erb view files. I only want to query the postgres-db and display that piece of data. I have a similar function that does return what I want, but this one does not. Any help much appreciated.

budget model:

```
  def self.total
    sql = "SELECT SUM(value) FROM budgets"
    response = SqlRunner.run(sql).first
    return response["sum"]
  end
```

controller:

```
get '/budgets' do
  @budgets = Budget.all
  @budget_total = Budget.total
  erb(:'budgets/index')
end
```

view/erb:

```
<p> Total budget:  <%= @budget_total %> </p>
```

Comment: What line is causing the error?

Comment: @budget_total = Budget.total  is where the error is. It doesn't recognise that function at all.

Comment: can you paste the error?

Comment: undefined method `total' for Budget:Class  >>  line 10 @budget_total = Budget.total  >>    /.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb

Answer (score 0):

Now it works, no error, no changes and the pry-byebug shot up. On a whim.

Conclusion: sometimes you just need to put the machine away and go for a walk in the forest.

Comment: Actually all that was required was to crash and then re-start the Sinatra web server. All else fails, try that.